# Verify that function solves PDE (how to differentiate the integral?)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $K(x,z)$ with $K(x,z)=0$ if $z<x$ solves $K_{xx}-K_{zz}=0$ and set
$$
\Psi(x,k)=e^{ikx}+\int_x^\infty K(x,z)e^{ikz}\, dz.
$$

Then, does $\Psi(x,k)$ solve the equation $\Psi_{xx}+k^2\Psi=0$ with $\Psi\sim e^{ikx}$ as $x\to\infty$?

---

It is clear that $\Psi\sim e^{ikx}$ as $x\to\infty$. But I have a problem to verify that $\Psi$ solves the equation $\Psi_{xx}+k^2\Psi=0$, because I do not know how to compute the $x-$derivative of the integral, i.e.,

$\Psi_x=ike^{ikx}+\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^\infty K(x,z)e^{ikz}\, dz$ and
$$
\Psi_{xx}=-k^2e^{ikx}+\frac{d^2}{d x^2}\int_{x}^\infty K(x,z)e^{ikz}\, dz
$$

Thus, in order to have that $\Psi$ is a solution, one would need that
$$
\frac{d^2}{d x^2}\int_{x}^\infty K(x,z)e^{ikz}\, dz=-k^2\int_x^\infty K(x,z)e^{ikz}\, dz.
$$

Comment: To get the first $x$--derivative you should treat the integral like a function $I(y,x)=\int_y^\infty K(x,z)e^{ikz}\,dz$. Differentiate that function w.r.t. $y$ and $x$ and then set $y=x$ and then take the sum of the partial derivatives of $I$. You are effectively applying the chain rule to $x\mapsto (x,x)\mapsto I(x,x)\,.$ The same principle then applies to the 2nd derivative.

Comment: But I do not know how to determine $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}I(y,x)$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}I(y,x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one needs the assumptions:
$$
\lim_{z\to\pm\infty}K(x,z)e^{ikz}=0\quad\text{ and }\quad\lim_{z\to\pm\infty}K_z(x,z)e^{ikz}=0\,.
$$
Because $K(x,z)=0$ for $z<x$ we can write
$$
\Psi(x,k)=e^{ikx}+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}K(x,z)\,e^{ikz}\,dz\,.
$$
This makes the differentiation w.r.t. $x$ much simpler:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Psi_{xx}(x,k)&=&-k^2\,e^{ikx}+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}K_{xx}(x,z)\,e^{ikz}\,dz\\
&=&-k^2\,e^{ikx}+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}K_{zz}(x,z)\,e^{ikz}\,dz\,.
\end{eqnarray}
Using integration by parts twice, the last integral is
\begin{eqnarray}
&&-ik\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} K_z(x,z)\,e^{ikz}\,dz+\underbrace{\Big[K_z(x,z)\,e^{ikz}\Big]^{z=+\infty}_{z=-\infty}}_{0\text{ by assumptions }}\\
&=&-k^2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} K(x,z)\,e^{ikz}\,dz+ik\underbrace{\Big[K(x,z)\,e^{ikz}\Big]^{z=+\infty}_{z=-\infty}}_{0\text{ by assumptions }}\,.
\end{eqnarray}
Altoghether this shows $\Psi_{xx}=-k^2\Psi\,.$